# How do I add spaces to each column in a range, where the character counts of each column equals 20?

Tags: excel, vba

There is a program I use that only takes data with 20 characters in each cell. Each column has the same number of characters per cell, but they vary from one to eight. Is there anyway to enter spaces in each cell so that they add up to 20 characters?

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim rang As range
Dim colA As range

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("osbstd")
Set rng = ws1.range("A1:FJ10000")
Set colA = ws1.range("A1:A10000")

For Each one In Selection
   If colA.Value <> "" Then colA.Value = colA.Value & Space(19)
Next
```

Looking for a simpler way to do this instead of dimming each column (because there is 23 columns) and doing an if statement for each column

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub tgr()

    'Change this to be the columns you need to adjust
    Const sColumns As String = "A:D,F:F"

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rArea As Range
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim rLast As Range
    Dim aData() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("osbstd")

    For Each rArea In ws.Range(sColumns).Areas
        Set rLast = rArea.Find("*", rArea.Cells(1), xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
        If Not rLast Is Nothing Then
            With rArea.Resize(rLast.Row)
                If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
                    ReDim aData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
                    aData(1, 1) = .Value
                Else
                    aData = .Value
                End If
                For i = 1 To UBound(aData, 1)
                    For j = 1 To UBound(aData, 2)
                        If Len(aData(i, j)) > 0 Then aData(i, j) = Left(aData(i, j) & Space(20), 20)
                    Next j
                Next i
                .Value = aData
                Erase aData
            End With
        End If
    Next rArea

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the simplest way to do that is like this :

```
Dim result As String
For j = 1 To 23
    For i = 1 To 10000
        result = Cells(i, j).Value
        Do While Len(result) < 20
            result = result & " "
        Loop
        Cells(i, j).Value = result
    Next i
Next j
```